# O(nlogn) in Javascript algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

The following function:

```
function solution(K, A) {
    var counter=0;
    for (var i=0;i<A.length;i++) {
        for (var j=i;j<A.length;j++) {
            if (A[i]+A[j]===K) {
              if (i===j)
               counter++;
              else
               counter+=2;  
            }
        }   
    }
    return counter;
}
```

finds the number of the pair elements inside an array A which have a sum of K. I**s it O(n^2/2)?** Is there another algorithm to implement the above with `O(nlogn)`?

Comment: Why is the counter incremented on i==j? It's probably  not a pair if it's the same index.

Comment: Actually, you can go one better and solve this problem in O (n) by using a lookup table. It's a standard interview question.

Comment: Yes it is n^2.  If the array is unordered then I don't think you can get any better than that.

Comment: You can make it O(n lgn) if you sort the array first then binary search on the list, but like suggested above you can solve it linearly with a hashmap

Comment: @nurdyguy Well you can sort it…

Comment: Can `A` contain duplicate elements? If yes, how should it treat them?

Comment: @Bergi  Very true, but then you add to the overall work.  You could add a bubble sort for n^2 then you could do this in nlogn.  You still end up with n^2.  I meant that if it was *already* sorted you could do better, otherwise you are kinda out of luck.

Comment: @nurdyguy: You can sort in `n log n`. Just don't use bubblesort.

Comment: @Bergi  Very true, bubblesort is nice simple code but not efficient.  My main point was that you'd be adding to the overall process if you had to first sort the array and then perform the desired function.  Of course nlogn + nlogn = nlogn so technically that is one answer to his problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the solution you have posted has `O(n^2)` complexity because of the two for loops. You can actually solve the problem in `O(n)` by using a `map` which is just an associative array in JavaScript.

```
function solution(k, arr){
    var map = {};
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length ; i++){
        var tmp = k - arr[i];
        if (temp > 0 && map[tmp] == 1)
            console.log("Found the pair :", temp, arr[i]);
        else
            map[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `map` should probably be an object, not an array.

Comment: Associate array is indeed an object in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find pairs of elements that have sum K in O(nlog n) you should create a new array in which you store a sorted version of the array that has been passed as a parameter, then do the following:

```
var i = 0;
var j = A.length - 1;
while(i < j) {

    if(A[i] + A[j] == k) {

        counter++;
        ++i;
        --j;
    }
    else
        if(A[i] + A[j] < k) {

            ++i;
        } 
        else
            ++j;
}
```

Now the sorting takes *O(nlogn)* and the above code *O(n)*, which makes it *O(nlogn)*.